# Running conda with proxy

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda 2.7 on windows, and my internet connection uses a proxy.

Previously, when using python 2.7 (Not Anaconda), I installed package like this:

```
pip install {packagename} --proxy proxy-us.bla.com:123
```

Is there a way to run `conda` with proxy argument? didn't see it in `conda help`.

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can configure a proxy with conda by adding it to the `.condarc`, like

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

or set the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables. Note that in your case you need to add the scheme to the proxy url, like https://proxy-us.bla.com:123.

See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server.

Comment: Thanks... to be honest, I saw this like much earlier, but I'm more interested in command-line solution, without editing some files... Do you know such?

Comment: Setting those environment variables is a command line solution.

Comment: If you are failing on an SSLError message, make sure you set `ssl_verify: False`. It maybe the case that your employer is decrypting your connection so the SSL certificate is not the one expected (man-in-the-middle attack)

Comment: I would avoid setting `ssl_verify: False`, unless you know for a fact that your employer is the one man in the middling you. By disabling ssl verification, you are completely disabling the security checks that ensure that conda ia downloading the packages it is supposed to. Remember that the packages conda downloads can run arbitrary code!

Comment: If I don't want to put my user name and password in the `.condarc` for security reason, and prefer to be asked to type them when needed, what should I do?

Comment: @kitman0804 I believe if you omit it it should prompt you to enter it when necessary.

Comment: @asmeurer No it don't. It gives me error message `CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-32/repodata.json.bz2>` and said something like `'Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required'`, if I don't put my user name and password in the file.

Comment: @kitman0804 I would open an issue at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues about it.

Answer (score 81):

Or you can use the **command line** below from version [4.4.x](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/5310/commits).

```
conda config --set proxy_servers.http http://id:pw@address:port
conda config --set proxy_servers.https https://id:pw@address:port
```

Comment: This did the job for me! :)

Comment: Probably a bit late now, but I wonder if phyatt had an updated version of anaconda? On 4.3.30 I get `CondaValueError: Key 'proxy_servers.http' is not a known primitive parameter.`

Comment: This worked for me! Weird enough, when I set the values directly in the file, they were not recognized. (conda 4.8.2)

Comment: This is working for both Windows and Linux. Thank you sm.

Comment: I'm running a px (https://github.com/genotrance/px) proxy on my host to authenticate with credentials behind corporate firewall. My px is listening on port 3131. I use RUN conda config --set proxy_servers.http http://host.docker.internal:3131
RUN conda config --set proxy_servers.https http://host.docker.internal:3131
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

Answer (score 15):

One mistake I was making was saving the file as `a.condarc` or `b.condarc`.

Save it only as `.condarc` and paste the following code in the file and save the file in your home directory. Make necessary changes to hostname, user etc.

```
channels:
- defaults

show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@hostname:port
    https: http://user:pass@hostname:port


ssl_verify: False
```

Comment: Isn't setting ssl_very to false inviting a man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: It is making it possible yes (inviting is going a bit far), the reason why it is probably mentioned in a post concerning proxy settings is that this is exactly what many proxies do. It is a "securityfeature" called SSL Scanning that certain antivirus proxy solutions offer and if you do not turn the verify off the download will fail because the proxies sign with their own cert afterwards. So this can very well be needed if you are behind a company proxy e.g.. Of course you are right in that one should try it and if it works without leave this line out.

Answer (score 6):

The **best way** I settled with is to **set proxy environment variables right before** using `conda` or `pip` install/update commands. Simply run:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy_url:port
```

For example, your actual command could be like

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://yourname:your_password@proxy.your_company.com:8080
```

If your company uses https proxy, then also

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:password@proxy_url:port
```

Once you exit Anaconda prompt then this setting is gone, so your username/password won't be saved after the session.

I didn't choose other methods mentioned in [Anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/proxy/) or some other sources, because they all require hardcoding of username/password into

- Windows environment variables (also this requires restart of Anaconda prompt for the first time)
- Conda `.condarc` or `.netrc` configuration files (also this won't work for PIP)
- A batch/script file loaded while starting Anaconda prompt (also this might require configuring the path)

All of these are unsafe and will require constant update later. And if you forget where to update? More troubleshooting will come your way...

Comment: This allows me to create anaconda environments, but I still cannot install stuff with `conda install`

Comment: You still have your username/password stored in your command history. It would be a lot safer to type at least the password into a prompt.

Comment: `also this won't work for PIP` should be highlighted with bold and caps

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it working without putting in  the username and password:

```
conda config --set proxy_servers.https https://address:port
```

Comment: but are you still prompted to put your credentials, or is a login-free proxy server?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure a proxy with conda by adding it to the .condarc, like

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

Then in cmd Anaconda Power Prompt (base) PS C:\Users\user> run:

```
conda update -n root conda
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac what worked for me was going to keychain and updating the password for the key that for the company's the internal repo.