# Anaconda CondaHTTPError/SSLError

Tags: ssl, anaconda

When I tried to execute "conda update conda", I had this error:
[image]

May you help me please!

Comment: Did this issue ever get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a firewall or proxy you may have to set `ssl_verify` to `false` in your condarc.

In our corporate environment our proxy modifies certificates so ssl verification will fail. In addition we have to set the http and https proxies explicitly.

You can find an example of a .condarc file with these settings in [How to make anaconda work behind http proxy not https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729023/how-to-make-anaconda-work-behind-http-proxy-not-https/36934565)

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy with a self-signed certificate authority I have given a detailed answer here:

[How to add a custom CA Root certificate to the CA Store used by Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-python-in-window/52961564#52961564)