# Installing packages with anaconda behind a http proxy

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, anaconda

I am trying to install the package langdect in Anaconda

As I am working in an office, I tried to set up the proxy by creating a .condarc file in C:\Users\my_username

In this file I put

```
channels:
  - defaults

show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
    http: http://username:passwordwith%escape@proxyhost:8080
    https: https://username:passwordwith%escape@proxyhost:8080

ssl_verify: True
```

But i got the following error when executing `conda update conda`

```
ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 
(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 au thenticationrequired')))"))
```

I already tried the solution on this question [How to make Anaconda work behind HTTP proxy (not https)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729023/how-to-make-anaconda-work-behind-http-proxy-not-https)

But I have some questions, is there an easy way to check my proxy blocked out the repository url? What else can I try to make it work?