# How to solve an error that appears in conda proxy configuration?

Tags: python, conda, rdkit

I am trying to install Rdkit on ubuntu and I have problem with the conda configuration.

I have reinstalled anaconda3 and python3 versions on my desktop and installed it from the beginning.

When I run the command: `conda create -c rdkit -n my-rdkit-env rdkit`

The error I am experiencing is this one:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem, so that I can install the program called Rdkit?

Comment: Do you have a `.condarc` in your home directory that contain any proxy settings? Have you set `HTTP_PROXY` and or `HTTPS_PROXY`? Do you even need a proxy server set?

Answer (score 9):

I had this same error message when creating a new environment in Anaconda prompt using the command

`conda create -n envname`

Please see this answer in another similar question. It solved the problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724703/9455395

Open your .condarc file and type the proxy servers as follows:

```
proxy_servers:
   http: proxyserver.org:portNumber
   https: proxyserver.org:portNumber
```

Make sure that the inputs **do not include "http://" or "https://"**. Simply use the same server address in both.

The other user also made the note to add anaconda.org as well as anaconda.com to proxy server exceptions. I did not need to carry out this step.

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10 OS

Comment: To find your proxy, on Windows 10, try `Settings -> Network & Internet -> Proxy -> Address + Port`, that for `proxyserver.org:portNumber` in this answer.

Comment: Make sure that you use spaces instead of tabs, or you'll run into an "invalid yaml" error when trying to use conda.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error on my work machine. I'm on Windows 10.

For me, the fix was to add `*.anaconda.org` to my list of proxy exceptions under *Control Panel* > *Internet Options* > *Connections* > *LAN Settings* > *Advanced*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I had the same error.

In my case was that in environment variables from my computer I had

```
     HTTP_PROXY = value... 
     HTTPS_PROXY
```

In my case I didnt need that and I just removed them and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
unset  https_proxy
unset  http_proxy
unset  no_proxy
unset  HTTPS_PROXY
unset  HTTP_PROXY
unset  NO_PROXY
```

This worked for me when I proxy error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Conda cannot continue due to proxy configuration errors.

The solutions are as follows:
Open "Internet Options" in the Internet -> Connection -> LAN Settings -> uncheck the "Use a proxy server for Lan".

Comment: This may work, but doesn't this reduce the security of your internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following settings in the `.condarc` and it worked:

```
channels:
- defaults

show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
    http: 127.0.0.1:<Cntlm_Port_number>
    https: 127.0.0.1:<Cntlm_Port_number>

ssl_verify: True
```

**Note**: In my machine, our IT team had set a Proxy and if I turn off that proxy I cannot have access to the internet at all. With that said, I used the above config and now I can run `conda create --name <env_name>`

PS: By Cntlm I mean [this](https://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today on Linux 18.04. I solved it by adding my username and password when exporting the `$http_proxy` and `$https_proxy`

Here is an command structure:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
$ export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxy:port
```

If your password contain special character such as `!@#$%`, make sure to input it as Flash code. For example `#->%23, @->%40`. You can search it for more symbol.

Also I have removed the `.condarc` file from the home directory.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: Hi I face the same issue now. Earlier it used to work. But now I get the above error.

My proxies are stored in ~/.bash_profile and not on .condarc. I guess after updating system, it has stopped working

Answer (score 1):

To run Conda on Linux without the error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.
```

Execute the following commands to unset these agents:

```
unset  https_proxy
unset  http_proxy
unset  no_proxy
unset  HTTPS_PROXY
unset  HTTP_PROXY
unset  NO_PROXY
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error on Linux OS.

Solution- To fix the error, I have added ( ***.anaconda.com** ) to the list of proxy exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on windows 10

1. close the proxy software
2. setting-> network and internet-> proxy-> stop using proxy server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my Windows 10.

I solved it by:

1. try to close the proxy software;
2. setting-> network and internet-> proxy-> take off "use a proxy server" .
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDDYk.png)

Or Open Control panel -> Internet Options -> Connection -> LAN Settings -> uncheck the "Use a proxy server for your Lan".

Answer (score 0):

Unusual and silly but still

I ran into this problem because was operating under VPN. Turning it off fixed this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the Problem when i was trying to install ipykernel " conda install ipykernel " so I solved it like this
go to internet options in your setting > connections > LAN settings > then uncheck the box with " use a proxy server for lan"
it worked for me and hope fully for you too