# Conda proxy problem when using home wifi network

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda, http-proxy

I installed anaconda in my work laptop and used the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797984/how-to-solve-an-error-that-appears-in-conda-proxy-configuration) to solve the proxy problem encountered when using the company's wifi network to update/install packages with `conda` or `pip`.

However, that solution (adding proxy to the condarc file) didn't work when I tried to update/install packages when using my home's wifi network.

This is a typical output when trying to install packages with home network regardless of with or without proxy setting in the `codarc` file, or disabling the proxy in internet connection setting

```
(base) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge keras
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.
```

[image]

Could someone please explain what happened here? Thanks.

Comment: You need to remove the proxy settings when using your home network. You will not be able to reach your companies proxy. Or are you using some kind of VPN solution?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @FlyingTeller. I did think of and actually removed the proxy settings when using my home network but still couldn't connect my anaconda program with internet to download packages. I guess the company intentionally setup its staff's laptops that way for security reason. You're right, my work around is to use VPN when connected to home network.

Comment: Can you post the output of a `conda install` command when in your home network? I am assuming that the internet connection works in general?

Comment: I added the output in the OP. Yes, my internet connection works fine as another workaround I discovered was to download the wheel file of the package then use `pip install <the wheel file>`.

Comment: `due to an error in your proxy configuration` lloks like it is still picking up proxy settings from somewhere (I guess you removed them from your `.condarc`), but there might still be some in your networking settings, check in `Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy`. `pip install <the wheel file>` is of course a workaround, but one should probably try to get `conda` to work, as you should prefer `conda` over `pip` as much as possible