Persistent SSL problems when enabling conda install through web proxy
I modified my condarc file to enable Conda installs through our web proxy and to hopefully resolve SSL errors.  However, I am still getting SSL errors.
c:/Users/User.Name/.condarc
---------------------------
channels:
  - defaults

# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724703
proxy_servers:
  http: webproxy.My.Organization.ca:8080
  https: webproxy.My.Organization.ca:8080

ssl_verify: C:\Users\User.Name\Certificates\MWGProxyRootCA.crt
# Result of
# https://aafaqueabdullah.wordpress.com/2017/04/10/ssl-authentication:
#    conda config --set ssl_verify True
#    conda config --set ssl_verify C:\Users\User.Name\Certificates\MWGProxyRootCA.crt

The web proxy URL is from the Windows proxy settings.  The ssl_verify file is created as follows:

Use Chrome to visit an Anaconda package page, e.g.,
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ascii_graph
Click on the lock icon to the left of the URL.  Sometimes, the icon is a pair of sliders to indicate controls of sorts.
In the resulting menu, click on "Connection is secure"
In the resulting panel, click on "Certificate is valid"
In the resulting panel, select the Details tab
In the "Certificate Hierarchy" section, choose MWGProxyRootCA
Click the Export button on the bottom right, then provide a
target path when prompted


Here is the resulting certificate:

Here is the SSL error:
(base) C:\>conda activate TestEnv (TestEnv)
C:\>conda install -c conda-forge ascii_graph
Collecting package metadata
(current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most
likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
(Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))

In the condarc file, if I prefix the web proxy URLs with http:// and https://, I get a different error:
(base) C:\>conda activate TestEnv

(TestEnv) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge ascii_graph
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an
error in your proxy configuration.  Check for
typos and other configuration errors in any
'.netrc' file in your home directory, any
environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and
any other system-wide proxy configuration
settings.

None of these errors seem to be affected by whether I append a trailing / to the web proxy URLs.
I followed a colleague's advice and issued conda update conda from the base environment of a newly launched Conda prompt, and from a different network than the one requiring proxy.  All went well, but the above problems persist on the network that uses proxy.
As per this answer, I also tried setting environment variables
HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY, but it doesn't change anything:
(base) C:\>set HTTP_PROXY=http://webproxy.My.Organization.ca:8080
(base) C:\>set HTTPS_PROXY=https://webproxy.My.Organization.ca:8080
(base) C:\>conda activate TestEnv
(TestEnv) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge ascii_graph
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most
likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
(Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))

Finally, as a blind attempt at something, I noticed that issuing set at the Conda prompt shows an environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE.  I set it to C:\Users\User.Name\Certificates\MWGProxyRootCA.crt from the condarc file and commented out that line in condarc.  I then tested this by activating environment TestEnv and trying a test install: conda install -c conda-forge ascii_graph.  It yielded more verbose SSL errors:
(TestEnv) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge
ascii_graph

Retrieving notices: ...working... ERROR
conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68):
Request error
<HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/pkgs/main/notices.json (Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))> for channel: defaults url:
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/notices.json

ERROR
conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68):
Request error
<HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/pkgs/msys2/notices.json (Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))> for channel: defaults url:
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/notices.json

ERROR
conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68):
Request error
<HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/pkgs/r/notices.json (Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))> for channel: defaults url:
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/notices.json

ERROR
conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68):
Request error
<HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/conda-forge/notices.json (Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))> for channel: conda-forge
url:
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/notices.json

done

Collecting package metadata
(current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most
likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
(Caused by
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c:1006)')))

I would like to avoid the solutions requiring a user name and password.  I would rather embed any solutions in condarc and forget about it.  I would also prefer not to disable SSL.
I am not a networking person.  What should my next step be?  If I need to talk to a networking person, what should I ask?

(0) probably not programming or development, and definitely not networking (1) Doubleclick your blahrootca.crt file -- does it show 'Issued to' (NOT 'by') as the root CA name? If not you didn't follow the instructions correctly. (2) If so, check if it is PEM format (which Windows imprecisely calls base64) by opening in notepad or equivalent: does it have human-readable ----BEGIN and ----END lines and otherwise all A-Za-z0-9+/=? Whether non-PEM (DER) works depends on whether your version of python uses the 'store' interface in a recent version of OpenSSL or not.

I agree, it's indirectly related to development in that it enables a development environment.  I noted the presence of similar questions on SO before posting. I added an image of the certificate from double-clicking the *.crt file and indeed, it shows the incorrect "issued by: MWGProxyRootCA". You said that this means I did something wrong. How would I properly generate the *.crt file? It does have -----BEGIN and -----END lines.

The cause of the errors is the improper generation of the certificate file.  Here is an illustration of the proper generation of the certificate (or at least, a method that works), including what lines were highlighted when I exported the certificate.  Following the bullet list in the originally posted question above:

The certificate can be saved to the *.crt file specified in .condarc, as shown in the originally posted question above.  As a test of success, this allowed the following to run from base environment of a new Conda prompt window:
(base) C:\>conda create --name TestEnv python
(base) C:\>conda activate TestEnv
(TestEnv) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge ascii_graph

The following is a transcript of the resulting successful session:
(base) C:\>conda create --name TestEnv python
WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location 'C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\TestEnv'
but it is not a conda environment.
Continue creating environment (y/[n])? y

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 24.7.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=24.7.1

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\TestEnv

  added / updated specs:
    - python

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  bzip2              pkgs/main/win-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h2bbff1b_6
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2024.7.2-haa95532_0
  expat              pkgs/main/win-64::expat-2.6.2-hd77b12b_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/win-64::libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-3.0.14-h827c3e9_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-24.0-py312haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.12.4-h14ffc60_1
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-72.1.0-py312haa95532_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.45.3-h2bbff1b_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/win-64::tk-8.6.14-h0416ee5_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2024a-h04d1e81_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h2eaa2aa_4
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.29.30133-h43f2093_4
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.43.0-py312haa95532_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/win-64::xz-5.4.6-h8cc25b3_1
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.13-h8cc25b3_1

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate TestEnv
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(base) C:\>conda activate TestEnv

(TestEnv) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge ascii_graph
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 24.7.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=24.7.1

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\TestEnv

  added / updated specs:
    - ascii_graph

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ascii_graph        conda-forge/noarch::ascii_graph-1.5.1-py_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2024.7.2-h~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2024.7.4-h56e8100_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(TestEnv) C:\>

