# Using a proxy with conda

Tags: python, anaconda

I need to configure a proxy in order to upgrade my Python environment in Anaconda. I specified the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=myproxy:8080
```

and modified the .condarc file in C:\Users\I328807:

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://myproxy:8080
```

but conda still struggles with the connection:

```
C:\Users\I328807>conda install python=3.5
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
```

Comment: Other example of same question, maybe it will be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099279/running-conda-with-proxy

Comment: I've read them but as I explained in my post, the definition of an environment variable and the configuration of the condarc file didn't solve the issue.

Comment: If you want to use command line, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099279/running-conda-with-proxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with an HTTP**S** proxy, not HTTP.

So the configuration should be,

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=myproxy:8080

proxy_servers:
    https: https://myproxy:8080
```

For more info, see here:
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server-proxy-servers

Comment: This worked... I supposed that the proxy was a HTTP one because the .pac configuration file just defines it with "PROXY myproxy:8080" but I was wrong. It seems the navigator is able to find out which type of proxy it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please can you retry this:

`export HTTP_PROXY` rather than set.

`sudo -E bash -c 'echo $HTTP_PROXY'` for making sure you export your variable.

Otherwise note that in your .condarc you cannot have tab between http: and declaration, only space.