# Schedule a Python script via batch on windows (using Anaconda)

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, anaconda, conda

I have a script that i run every day and want to make a schedule for it, i have already tried a batch file with:

`start C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\python.exe C:\script.py`

And im able to run some basic python commands in it, the problem is that my actual script uses some libraries that were installed with Anaconda, and im unable to use them in the script since Anaconda will not load.

Im working on windows and can't find a way to start Anaconda and run my script there automatically every day.

Answer (score 21):

I would be a bit careful in calling python directly through environment as one never knows if the internals for activate function has changed.

I'm just using basic bat-script to help me out.

```
SET log_file=%cd%\logfile.txt
call C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
cd \script_directory
python script.py arg1 arg2 > %log_file%
```

This script saves the log-file wherever the bat is run from, calls the right environment through activate (in this case the standard) and directs all the stdout into log-file for further investigation.

Then just point your Windows Task Scheduler to the script and set the home directory where you want the log-file to appear.

Answer (score 14):

I'd recommend creating an Anaconda environment with the packages you need, then using the python from that environment to run your script. Read about Anaconda environments [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

For example...

Say you create an environment called cristians_env

```
conda create --name cristians_env
```

and you install the packages you need

```
conda install pandas
```

Then, all you need to do is this from your batch script (assuming you use Anaconda 2)

```
start C:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\cristians_env\bin\python C:\script.py
```

and voila! You're using your anaconda environment from your batch script!

Comment: Thx! i just found another way but your method seems better!

Comment: thanks so much for posting this, was causing me a total headache

Comment: But in this way some modules may not be loaded, for example I'm using requests, I'm getting the error `"Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."`, I had to call the `.....\activate.bat` file before as mentioned by @HarshaLimaye

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. 
What I discovered is that *anaconda prompt* is nothing but your *usual cmd prompt* after running an **'activate.bat'** script which is located in the anaconda 'Scripts' folder. 
So to run your python scripts in anaconda all you need to do is write 2 lines in a batch file. (Open notepad and write the lines mentioned below. Save the file with **.bat** extension)

1. call C:\....path to anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
2. call python C:\path to your script\Script.py

Then you schedule this batch file to run as you wish and it will run without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, i copied the "activate.bat" file in "C:\Users\yo\Miniconda3\Scripts" and renamed it as schedule.bat and added my script (copy pasted it) on the end of the file.

Then i can schedule a task on windows that executes schedule.bat everyday

Answer (score 0):

it took me two days to find a solution to this. Hope it helps.
Command Prompt and Anaconda prompt are basically the same thing as far as Windows OS is concerned.
Now, you want to run a Python script via schedular daily using Anaconda prompt. Here are the steps:

1. **Download Python** (I downloaded Python 3.12) and add Path in environment variable.
2. Open a CMD and change the directory to where your python.exe is available. '**pip install** ' in this cmd for all the libraries you need to run your python script.
3. Write a **Windows Batch File** (.bat) as shown below:

```
@echo off
"C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe" "C:\Codes\MyScript.py"
```

4. Now **create a basic task** to run a program which would be the .bat file.
5. This way you will be able to run your Python script via the schedular. I will be happy to respond here for further help.