# Python scripts not running automatically or from shortcuts

Tags: python, anaconda, scheduled-tasks, spyder

I've encountered this problem a couple of days ago, which is around time when I updated python and some packages.

1. scripts run perfectly fine when I'm using Spyder,
2. scripts run perfectly fine when I'm using Anaconda command prompt and type:

   ```
   python 'filepath\filename.py'
   ```
3. scripts stop just after the start if I use scheduler (I use TaskTillDawn) or I run a windows shortcut

   ```
   python "filepath\filename.py"
   ```

   that then automatically converts to:

   ```
   c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe "filepath\filename.py"
   ```

All of the scripts were running fine before, through shortcuts, schedules etc.

Maybe the solution is obvious, but I don't see it, so any help would be appreciated. If you need more info, just tell me what it is :)

Cheers,

Comment: May be its helpful to do vise-versa, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437863/schedule-a-python-script-via-batch-on-windows-using-anaconda

Comment: It may not be enough to simply point to the Anaconda-distribution's Python interpreter since some packages edit the environment variables during env activatiion. Instead, you could try `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe run -n base python 'filepath\filename.py'`. You may need to adjust the path to `conda.exe` since I may not be recalling correctly where it is on Windows. I'm also assuming you are talking about your **base** env.