# Anaconda Python module importing issues when running Python script from batch file

Tags: python, windows, pandas, cmd

I want my Windows computer to automatically run a Python script every day, using the Task Scheduler. I wrote my Python Script using Spyder (Anaconda), and then I wrote a small batch file which looks like this:

```
set PATH="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages";%PATH%
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "path\to\my\python\script.py"
pause
```

note that I am manually adding `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages"` to my PATH variable, to ensure that my Anaconda Python distribution will correctly import the necessary modules, including `pandas` and `numpy`.

But when I run this batch script, the following error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\my\python\script.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

So it looks like Python wasn't able to import `numpy`, despite my specific action to add the `site-packages` folder to the PATH variable.

How can I solve this issue?

***EDIT: my question is quite similar to this one [Schedule a Python script via batch on windows (using Anaconda)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46437863/6103050)***

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859939/python-pandas-missing-required-dependencies-numpy-1

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved it by writing the following:

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
python "path\to\my\python\script.py"
```

The first command enables the Anaconda environment, ensuring that all the installed packages will be correctly imported when requested. Then the Python script is executed.

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/53363567/6103050

Comment: This was super helpful, worked for me, thanks R. Bourgeon, you saved me time/money/life essence.