# Import python packages not working when running .py script, but working if run in Jupyter

Tags: python, numpy, import, pip, anaconda

I created some Python code in Jupyter Notebook and I would like to automate its exections using Windows Task Manager. I made .py file basing on Jupyter Notebook. Jupyter Notebook runs just fine - there is no problems with importing and using numpy. When I run .py script I get:

```
import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.
# In english I believe it is: The specified module could not be found
```

I am working on Windows 10 and I am using Anaconda3. In anaconda-prompt I did `pip list` and checked it out: I have numpy installed. I am running my script by `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\My\script.py"`.

I think it is some configuration problem, do anyone know solution or ever encountered similiar errors?

Comment: Might be worth running from the Anaconda prompt instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule a Python script via batch on windows (using Anaconda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437863/schedule-a-python-script-via-batch-on-windows-using-anaconda)

Comment: Exactly. Adding call to Anaconda activate script was the key. Thank you!