# not able to create conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

There is an error message when i try to create an environment.
I have installed Anaconda3 and it is with python3.7 and i have set the environment variable on my window10 machine. With the use of jupyter notebook i do my works on machine learning. But i am not be able to import tensorflow library on it.
So I tried to install an environment. on my cmd i tried

```
conda create -n tfp3.6 python=3.6
C:\>conda create -n tfp3.6 python=3.6
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

And this is my environment variables
[this is my environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2DV8.png)

please help.
Thanks inadvance

Comment: might it be an internet connection problem?

Comment: Adding to @JoshFriedlander, your network might be blocking the anaconda repo. Highly possible if you're using your work network.

Comment: This sounds like a proxy issue.  If you're on a work network, do they have a proxy server you need to connect through?  See [Running conda with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099279/running-conda-with-proxy) for hints on how to make it work.  You will need to get the proxy server information from your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be a case of Python3.7 issue on some Windows systems.

The root of problem hide in tail of error-message: "SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")"

This issue occur for Python3.7 running on some Windows (I suffered it on Windows 10).
The solution is: install and use Python3.6

P.S.:
In my case, I found the very tricky exhibition of this problem: code successfully run under conda-shell, successfully run under Jupyter-notebook, but fails to run from cmd with python.exe taken from either conda installation or conda-created environment.

To be sure you suffer the same problem, you may run this line in cmd:

python -c "import requests; response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.ru', cert=False); print(response);"

(suppose requests package is installed, for instance via cmd execution: "pip install requests")

This cmd execution should success to run under anaconda-shell, but fails to run under python3.7