# Python Anaconda Create Environment (proxy set): Invalid IPv6 URL

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda, ipv6

I have just installed Anaconda on my Windows 7 machine. I am now trying to set up a virtual environment to work from for my project. The first problem I think I have already fixed is the proxy settings in the .conarc file. I did this by following the instructions in the following answer to the question  [Running conda with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099279/running-conda-with-proxy). However, when I try to create a new environment, I am now running into the following error message "Invalid IPv6 URL". Can anyone advise how to solve this?

Copy of the error report below:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", lin
e 1062, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.
py", line 82, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py"
, line 37, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", li
ne 256, in install
        force_reinstall=context.force_reinstall or context.force,
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", lin
e 112, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", lin
e 150, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", lin
e 249, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line
 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", lin
e 389, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", lin
e 974, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", lin
e 214, in get_reduced_index
        repodata_fn=repodata_fn)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py
", line 91, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586,
 in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432,
 in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384,
 in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57,
 in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py
", line 87, in <lambda>
        package_ref_or_match_spec))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py
", line 96, in query
        self.load()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py
", line 160, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py
", line 234, in _load
        repodata_fn=self.repodata_fn)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py
", line 471, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        timeout=timeout)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", li
ne 546, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", li
ne 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", li
ne 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", li
ne 412, in send
        conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", li
ne 304, in get_connection
        proxy = prepend_scheme_if_needed(proxy, 'http')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line
895, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
        scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(url, new_scheme
)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 368, in urlparse

        splitresult = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 432, in urlsplit

        raise ValueError("Invalid IPv6 URL")
    ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL

`$ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create --name py37 python=3.
7`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe

               CONDA_EXES="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.ex
e"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\a08056114
                     PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Libr
ary\mingw-w64\bi
                          n;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramD
ata\Anaconda3\Li
                          brary\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramD
ata\Anaconda3\bi
                          n;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Li
brary\mingw-w64\
                          bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Progra
mData\Anaconda3\
                          Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Progra
mData\Anaconda3\
                          bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\WINDOWS\syste
m32;C:\WINDOWS;C
                          :\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPow
erShell\v1.0;C:\
                          WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\Sys
tem32\WindowsPow
                          erShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.
0;C:\WINDOWS\Sys
                          tem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Windo
wsPowerShell\v1.
                          0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Progra
m Files
                          (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\OpenText\Viewer\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennh
eiser\SoftphoneS
                          DK;C:\Users\a08056114\Documents\Software\snap\bin
        PLMVIS_82_LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\Program
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\
system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\a08056114\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\a08056114\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.10
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=7.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\a08056114\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\a08056114\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\a08056114\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\a08056114\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/7 W
indows/6.1.7601
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else. I discovered the proxy in fact hadn't been set properly and this was still the cause of the issue. The reason it wasn't set properly is because I had the character # in my password. Once I changed my password to remove all the #'s it worked.